# Redesign DB to get rid of aggregation

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-design, aggregation-framework

I have a collection (currently it has over 10 millions documents) with analytics data. 
Example of doc from `clicks` collection:

```
{
  serverId: 'srv1',
  dateVisited: '2014-12-24',
  campaignId: 'c1',
  ...
  landingpageClicks: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ],
  offerTrackings: [
    {
      amount: 10
    },
    {
      amount: 22
    }
    {
      amount: 18
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to pull reports from this collection. User can request grouping by multiple fields, e.g. group by date, then by `serverId`, then by `campaignId` and report should look like this:

```
2014-12-24    |  50 lp clicks  |  21 offer clicks  | $600 // srv1 + srv2
  srv1        |  20 lp clicks  |  11 offer clicks  | $400 // campaign1 + campaign2
    campaign1 |  10 lp clicks  |   6 offer clicks  | $100
    campaign2 |  10 lp clicks  |   5 offer clicks  | $300
  srv2        |  30 lp clicks  |  10 offer clicks  | $200 // campaign3 + campaign4
    campaign3 |  20 lp clicks  |   4 offer clicks  | $100
    campaign4 |  10 lp clicks  |   6 offer clicks  | $100
```

Currently I use following query to pull reports, but it's extremely slow:

```
db.clicks.aggregate([
  {$match: {'_id.dateVisited': '2014-12-24'}},
  {$group:{
    _id: '$_id.dateVisited',
    totalLandingpageClicksCount: {$sum: '$value.landingpageClicksCount'},
    totalOfferTrackingsCount: {$sum: '$value.offerTrackingsCount'},
    totalOfferTrackingsAmount: {$sum: '$value.offerTrackingsAmount'}
  }}
])
```

My idea was to create separate collection for each possible combinations of fields and use `find({<search + group fields>})` instead of aggregation. I.e. if user requests report for specific date interval, grouped by `serverId`, then by `campaignId`, the following queries will be used:

```
//example of doc in dateVisited_serverId collection
{
  _id: {
   dateVisited: '...',
   serverId: '..'
  },
  value: {
    <counts>
  } 
}
// get stats for date, grouped by serverId
db.dateVisited_serverId.find({
 '_id.dateVisited': {
  '$gte': dateFrom,
  '$lte': dateTo
 }
}) 


//example of doc in dateVisited_serverId_campaignId collection
{
  _id: {
   dateVisited: '...',
   serverId: '..',
   campaignId: '..'
  },
  value: {
    <counts>
  } 
}
// get stats for date, grouped by serverId and then by campaignId
db.dateVisited_serverId_campaignId.find({
 dateVisited: {
  '$gte': dateFrom,
  '$lte': dateTo
 },
 serverId: {$in: [<server ids from previous query>]}
})
```

It would work, but the `clicks` collection have 18 fields, so I have to generate **245760** collections to implement my idea.

That way I need to find another design for my DB.

**[UPDATE] example of real document:**

```
{
   "_id": {
     "dateVisited": ISODate("2014-11-05T00:00:00.0Z"),
     "campaignId": "4c29dc888be98a9488e6876133852c72",
     "landingpageId": "c5557aedab04ad1444b0ee28b5ddaab9",
     "offerId": null,
     "trafficAccountId": "84d06369b9872e9a2685483b7a532a10",
     "serverId": "32",
     "browser": "Safari",
     "platform": "Android",
     "c1": "chat",
     "c2": "au",
     "c3": "12b-ad1a",
     "c4": "mtv2",
     "city": "Perth",
     "country": "Australia",
     "deviceType": "mobile",
     "isp": "Telstra Internet",
     "netspeedId": NumberLong(3),
     "set": "" 
  },
   "value": {
     "lpCount": 2,
     "offersCount": 0,
     "grandConversionCount": 0,
     "grandConversionAmount": 0 
  } 
}
```

Comment: How many documents are there for one day? Why are you grouping on `_id.dateVisited` instead of grouping on `null` or some other constant value - all documents belong to the same group due to the `$match`. It'd be good to show a more complicated/realistic example than the most simple case since it has a big effect on the pipeline. Why aren't you using a date field for the date? It will be faster than a string, for one. What indexes do you have, specifically? You need an index on `_id.dateVisited`.  Can you show us an explain for a slow aggregation?

Comment: ~10 000 per day. grouping on `_id.dateVisited` - because I need statistics grouped by date. In real collection date field is used. I have index on `_id.dateVisited` - $match works pretty fast. But if user selects 1 year as date range, then $group have to process `365*1000 = ~3,650,000` of docs. And it's very slow

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you have any indexes. In case you don't please build and index on `dateVisited` and check your performance again.

Depending on your site's traffic you may drop the index during normal use since it makes inserts slower and build it when you need to create the reports.

Comment: Yes, I have indexes, but $group does not use index data. The bottleneck of my aggregation is $group, not $match